# É possível apagar o history do navegador?

Tags: javascript, navegador-de-internet, histórico

Existe alguma maneira de eliminar via javascript todo o histórico do navegador?

O navegador está acumulando cerca de 46 históricos no meu site, e não consigo reduzir isso nem com reza brava:

Já tentei com:

```
history.pushState(null, null, location.href);
```

Com isso também:

```
for (var i=0; i <= window.history.length; i++) {
    window.location.replace('/home');
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Respondendo ao:

> É possível apagar o history do navegador?

**Não existe meio nativo e nem garantido de resolver isso** e **não há motivos para limpar o history do usuário**.

Digo isso porque o navegador é do usuário, mesmo que o site seja seu, o usuário decide como ele deve e quer navegar, não você, o que você pode fazer é facilitar, um meio de evitar histórico, se for um sistema interno, é fazer tudo em Ajax (SE FOR UM SISTEMA INTERNO, se for um site normal não faça isso, vai só atrapalhar).

> Devo ressaltar, o segundo código não tem sentido:
>
> ```
> for (var i=0; i <= window.history.length; i++) {
>     window.location.replace('/home');
> }
> ```
>
> só esta forçado um redirecionamento direto quando entra no loop, provavelmente isso esta disparando sem parar.

Agora dá pra até tentar algumas coisas, não é garantido (ou seja, não testei em todos navegadores), mas o que pode tentar fazer é usar o o `history.go()` para voltar a primeira e depois setar o `window.location` usando uma hash para diferenciar

```
history.go(-history.length + 1);
setTimeout(function () { location = location.href + '#1'; }, 500);
```

> PS: `pushState` não funcionou

Ou então fixar a página:

```
history.go(-history.length + 1);
setTimeout(function () { location = 'https://pt.stackoverflow.com/#1'; }, 500);
```

Vale lembrar que a hash é para diferenciar a primeira URL, pois senão ele não irá diferenciar, funcionando como um "reload" ao invés de substituir as demais

O timeout é apenas uma garantia, sobre o carregamento, em alguns testes que fiz foi necessário, dependendo do site/página.

Claro que usar #1 em todos não vai dar certo, então teria que usar uma hash que diferente de uma possivel existente hash da primeira página, mas se for o caso também poderia manipular a querystring con `/?querystring=foo&bar=baz&_history=1`, trocando `_history={novo valor}` sempre que for a primeira, se não tiver querystring então ficaria apenas `?_history=1`

Answer (score 3):

Não é possível fazer isso (até porque, se fosse possível, representaria um tipo de "risco de segurança" para os utilizadores).

Vale salientar que o `history.length` computa todo o histórico da **sessão** do usuário (de uma aba, por exemplo). Desse modo, esse número pode ir muito além da navegação feita em seu próprio website.

Apagar essa informação seria apagar a possibilidade do usuário voltar à página anterior que ele mesmo navegou, isto é, seu JavaScript poderia acabar fazendo uma ação que prejudica a experiência do usuário de modo geral.

---

Se você tem uma aplicação SPA (que faz as navegações diretamente pelo *browser* usando a API [`history`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState)), você pode optar por utilizar o método [`replaceState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/replaceState), que, ao contrário do [`pushState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState), não adiciona mais um item à *stack* do histórico (portanto, o `length` fica inalterado).

Se você está num ambiente de extensão, você pode usar a API [`browser.history.deleteAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/history/deleteAll). Nesse caso, como o usuário explicitamente instalou a extensão, esta pode ter a permissão de fazer esse tipo de ação.

Comment: Gostei desse replaceState, não havia pensado nisso, é uma boa.